# Intranet website

Tags: internet-explorer, iis-6

Some days ago, I started Internet Explorer as a different user to test one of my Intranet website hosted on a test server, but since that day whenever I open that same website it opens it as the different user windows credential.

My username is MyUID, I started IE as OtherUID to open http://testServer. Since that day whenever I try opening http://testServer, system itself takes credential as OtherUID rather than MyUID. I have tried clearing local cache from IE, I have tried deleting all temp files, but no success.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://yourUser@testServer which should specify a different user. Password can be supplied using user:password unless you're prompted.

Comment: But I dont want to supply it my username and password, it should use currently logged in user's windows credentials, because the website is configured to use "Windows Authentication".